# Open questions in algebraic geometry that need insights from computations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, open-problem

I think that everything is in the question.

I am looking for any open problems in algebraic geometry (vector bundles, Divisors, Frobenius morphism, counting points on Finite fields, Hitchin Fibration, (semi)stability of vector bundles) where some input from computations (cohomologie groups,...) is needed in order to shed light or make progress and better understand these open questions.

Comment: Mumford and Bayer have a paper called [What can be computed in algebraic geometry?](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9304003) that you might find useful.

Comment: Many thanks! I will check the paper.

Comment: I mean...there are huge swaths of algebraic geometry that kind of boil down to computations of sheaf cohomology groups. I think this question really needs more information as to what you mean by computation. Are you specifically talking about the use of computers to do "large" computations?

Comment: @TabesBridges, I am actually interested in open questions in algebraic geometry where we don't know much mainly because we don't have enough data, or enough examples. To give an example: the Hitchin fibers may be very singular if the rank $r$ and degree $d$ of considered vector bundles are not coprime. In this specific question, do we have infinitely may cases where the fibers are singular or there is a fixed $d_0$ with $(d_0,r) \ne 1 $ for which fibers are regular for $(d,r) \ne 1 $ and $d\ge d_0$? Depending on the answer, algebraic geometers would have interesting problems to tackle

Comment: My question was actually not restricted to computer large computations.

Comment: I see. I can't think of a problem like this, but here's a situation that is somehow the opposite of what you're asking for, which I could see being of interest: the $F$-conjecture predicts the structure of the cone of ample divisors (or equivalently by duality the Mori cone of curves) on the moduli space of pointed curves $\overline M_{g,n}$ (namely, that the extremal rays of the cone of curves are precisely the $1$-dimensional strata in the usual stratification of the boundary by topological type). The "Bridge Theorem" of Gibney-Keel-Morrison...

Comment: ...reduces this problem to the genus $0$ case and therefore to a combinatorial problem which their paper actually makes explicit; however, the combinatorial problem is so complex that I don't think they were able to prove even a single new case at the time with the help of a computer. In the two decades since GKM, people have tried chipping away at this problem in various ways. In fact a few years ago my advisor asked me a question that was, I think, aimed at producing a counterexample to the $F$-conjecture...

Comment: .....but told me to stop working on it after a paper came out that (by more theoretical methods) pushed the minimal $n$ for which a counterexample could occur up to something like $n=24$, which made the search no longer computationally feasible. So there are situations where all of the "computational low hanging fruit" has been worked out, and any computational advance would probably itself by a theoretical advance.

Comment: Many thanks @TabesBridges for sharing these conjectures, good example where computation would be of no help.